# Blogger still visible after moving to WP; Google Indexing issues after moving from Blogger to WP

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, blogger, migration

I recently migrated from Blogger to Wordpress and am having two major transition issues that are really hurting. Despite literally hours of searching and experimenting, I cannot resolve the following:

ISSUE ONE: I fixed all of my old blogger links to 301 redirect successfully to my WP links (the 2 structures are different and I realized too late), but my old blogger blog is still sometimes visible! (the 2 designs are completely different) I had 31 hits on my blogger site just yesterday. I have updated my privacy settings to hide my blogger blog from search engines and not be visible on blogger. I also removed my custom domain from blogger already as well. HELP! Not sure how to stop this.

ISSUE two: Despite submitting a new site map and reindexing my pages for my WP blog, I am not visible in search engines, although I was very visible previously. In fact, some of my OLD links are showing up. Am I being penalized?? Any thoughts on how to fix.

Comment: Are you using WordPress on the same domain which blogger was mapper to?

Comment: Another suggestion if you've already deleted your old sitemap from Google and Bing webmaster tools and have submitted a new one. You should install this hRecipe plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hrecipe/ it will generate microdata which Google and others recognize. Since you're posting recipes might as well get a little more SEO friendly. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the content is the same (and it will be since you migrated), it will be penalized. Can you try putting a canonical rel for each of your blogger post which links to your current WordPress post?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you'll have to do is setup a custom domain name in Blogger, have it redirect all the traffic to your current domain. Install this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-blogger-to-wordpress-301-redirector/ and it will redirect incoming traffic from Blogger to the appropriate post.

I can still see some of your blogger posts and they are not all redirecting.